# Android SMS Delivery Report not working properly

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent, smsmanager

Testing Hardware:
HUAWEI G750 Dual SIM CARD

Below Code broadcast SMS_SENT fine.While it always broadcast SMS_Delivered even though the receiving phone is off. It must be broadcast when the receiver received the SMS.

```html
//SEND SMS
private void SendSMS(int MessageID, String ToMobileNo, String MessageBody, int EncodingID)
{
 // Intent for Sending SMS
 String SendingIntentText = "SMS_SENT" + MessageID;
 Intent SendIntent = new Intent(SendingIntentText);
 SendIntent.putExtra("MessageID", MessageID);
 PendingIntent PendingSendIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, SendIntent, 0);

 // SENT SMS Broad Cast Receiver
 registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver()
 {
     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1)
     {
  int MessageID = arg1.getIntExtra("MessageID", 0);
 
  if (MessageID > 0)
  {
      switch (getResultCode())
      {
   case Activity.RESULT_OK:
       DBMethods.SendSMSCounter++;
       new DBMethods.SendSMSSuccess(MainActivity.this).execute(String.valueOf(MessageID));
       break;
   // following will call if message failed
   case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, MessageID + " Message Send Failed : RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       break;
   case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, MessageID + " Message Send Failed : RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       break;
   case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, MessageID + " Message Send Failed : RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       break;
   case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, MessageID + " Message Send Failed : RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       break;
      }
  }

     }
 }, new IntentFilter(SendingIntentText));

 // Intent For Delivery Report
 String DeliveryText = "SMS_DELIVERED" + MessageID;
 Intent DeliveryIntent = new Intent(DeliveryText);
 DeliveryIntent.putExtra("MessageID", MessageID);
 PendingIntent PendingDeliveryIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, DeliveryIntent, 0);

 // Delivery Report BroadCast Receiver
 registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver()
 {
     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1)
     {
  int MessageID = arg1.getIntExtra("MessageID", 0);
  if (MessageID != 0)
  {
      switch (getResultCode())
      {
   case Activity.RESULT_OK:
       DBMethods.DeliveredSMSCounter++;
       new DBMethods.SMSDeliverySuccess(MainActivity.this).execute(String.valueOf(MessageID));
       break;
   case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, MessageID + " Message Delivery Failed : RESULT_CANCELED ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       break;
      }
  }

     }
 }, new IntentFilter(DeliveryText));

 SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

 // Encoding English = 0 , Unicode = 2
 if (EncodingID == 0)
 {
     // 160 chars of single Message.
     if (MessageBody.length() > 160)
     {
  ArrayList<String> MessageList = smsManager.divideMessage(MessageBody);

  int MessageParts = MessageList.size();
  ArrayList<PendingIntent> PendingSendIntentList = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
  ArrayList<PendingIntent> PendingDeliveryIntentList = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();

  for (int i = 0; i < MessageParts; i++)
  {
      PendingSendIntentList.add(PendingSendIntent);
      PendingDeliveryIntentList.add(PendingDeliveryIntent);
  }
  smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(ToMobileNo, null, MessageList, PendingSendIntentList, PendingDeliveryIntentList);
     }
     else
     {
  smsManager.sendTextMessage(ToMobileNo, null, MessageBody, PendingSendIntent, PendingDeliveryIntent);
     }
 }
 else
 {
     // converting to bit code UTF-16
     String UniCodeSMS = null;
     try
     {
  byte[] utf16 = MessageBody.getBytes("UTF-16");
  UniCodeSMS = new String(utf16, "UTF-16");
     }
     catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex)
     {
  Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }

     // Sending Long SMS
     if (UniCodeSMS.length() > 70)
     {
  ArrayList<String> MessageList = smsManager.divideMessage(UniCodeSMS);

  int MessageParts = MessageList.size();
  ArrayList<PendingIntent> PendingSendIntentList = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
  ArrayList<PendingIntent> PendingDeliveryIntentList = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();

  for (int i = 0; i < MessageParts; i++)
  {
      PendingSendIntentList.add(PendingSendIntent);
      PendingDeliveryIntentList.add(PendingDeliveryIntent);
  }
  smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(ToMobileNo, null, MessageList, PendingSendIntentList, PendingDeliveryIntentList);
     }
     else
     {
  smsManager.sendTextMessage(ToMobileNo, null, UniCodeSMS, PendingSendIntent, PendingDeliveryIntent);
     }
 }

}
```

Comment: What is the problem? what error did you get?

Comment: No error.. the delivery report should be received when the sms received to the sender. while my code always broadcast delivery report that is the problem.

Comment: Hi @MSajjad, have you found the solution to this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```html
PendingIntent piSent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, sendIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
PendingIntent piDelivered = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, deliverIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```